# Ways in .NET to get an array of int from 0 to n

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm searching the way(s) to fill an array with numbers from 0 to a random. For example, from 0 to 12 or 1999, etc.

Of course, there is a `for`-loop:

```
var arr = int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  arr[i] = i;
}
```

And I can make this method been an extension for `Array` class. But is there some more interesting ways?

Comment: You could do some sort of functional implementation. You could populate a List<int> and use ToArray. Ultimately, I don't think there are any interesting solutions as the problem is not that interesting really.

Comment: What do you want to do with the array? I like 'configurator's solution...

Comment: Actually my solution gives you the same result as Enumerable.Range(0, n) - I forgot about that method for a while.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This already exists(returns IEnumerable, but that is easy enough to change if you need):

```
arr = Enumerable.Range(0, n);
```

Answer (score 7):

The most interesting way in my mind produces not an array, but an `IEnumerable<int>` that enumerates the same number - it has the benefit of O(1) setup time since it defers the actual loop's execution:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        yield return i;
}
```

This loop goes through all numbers from `0` to `max-1`, returning them one at a time - but it only goes through the loop when you actually need it.

You can also use this as `GetNumbers(max).ToArray()` to get a 'normal' array.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer depends on why you need the array. The thing is, the value of any array element is equal to the index, so accessing any element is essentially a redundant operation. Why not use a class with an indexer, that just returnes the value of the index? It would be indistinguishable from a real array and would scale to any size, except it would take no memory and no time to set up. But I get the feeling it's not speed and compactness you are after. Maybe if you expand on the problem, then a better solution will be more obvious.